# Sublime Text 2 crashes when I type "self"

Tags: crash, sublimetext2

I don't really know the reason behind this bug, but it just happens. This is what I'm trying to type until it crashes.

```
def __str__(self):
```

The moment I type ")", the program closes the window automatically.

I don't know if it's useful, but I use package control with the packages Djaneiro and Jedi.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but first you can check to see if it is the packages that are causing the problem. Go to your `Preferences.sublime-settings` and in the `"ignored_packages":` array add the names of your two packages. Now try and reproduce the problem. If there are no issues this time, that means it was one of those packages (you can find out which by doing the same thing with trial and error).

Comment: The problem was in the Jedi package. Not sure why, it doesn't happen when I type other things,